finding presentation for a group quotient modulo normal cyclic subgroup
Let $G$ be the group given by the following presentation
$$
G=\langle x,y:x^5=y^2\rangle
$$
Clearly, $x^5$ commutes with both $x$ and $y$, so $x^5\in Z(G)$. Hence $N=\langle x^5\rangle$ is normal subgroup of $G$.
My question: what is the presentation of the quotient $G/N$ ?
My attempt: I tried to find generators for $G/N$. I noticed that $(yN)^2=y^2N=x^5N=N$. I guess that $yN\in G/N$ is one of them. What could be the other?

Would $\langle x,y : x^5 = y^2 = 1 \rangle$ do it?

There is in general no such thing as "the presentation" (definite singular article) of a group. Groups generally have many distinct presentations.  You can talk about a presentation of $G/N$ (indefinite singular article).

Thanks  @Arturo, you right

Either by definition or using the properties of the free group, we know that $G=\langle x,y\mid x^5=y^2\rangle$ is isomorphic to $F/M$, where $F$ is the free group of rank $2$ generated by $x$ and $y$, and $M$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $F$ that contains the relator $x^5y^{-2}$.
By the isomorphism theorems, $N$ corresponds to the normal subgroup $\langle M,x^5\rangle$, and
$$\frac{G}{N} = \frac{F/M}{\langle M,x^5\rangle/M} \cong \frac{F}{\langle M,x^5\rangle}.$$
Now, $\langle M,x^5\rangle$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $F$ that contains both $x^5y^{-2}$ and $x^5$: it is clearly a normal subgroup that contains $x^5y^{-2}$ and $x^5$; and any  normal subgroup that contains $x^5y^{-2}$ must contain $M$, giving the reverse inclusion. Thus, $G/N$ is isomorphic to $F$ modulo the smallest normal subgroup that contains the relators $x^5y^{-2}$ and $x^5$; that is,
$$\frac{G}{N} = \langle x,y\mid x^5=y^2, x^5=1\rangle.\tag{$1$}$$
Since $\langle x^5y^{-2},x^5\rangle = \langle x^5,y^2\rangle$, we can also describe it as
$$\frac{G}{N} = \langle x,y\mid  x^5 = y^2 = 1\rangle.$$
In general, if you have a presentation
$$G = \langle X\mid R\rangle$$
and you have a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, then a presentation for $G/N$ can be given by
$$ \frac{G}{N} = \langle X \mid R\cup S\rangle$$
with $S = \{n_1=1,\ldots,n_k=1\}$, where $n_1,\ldots,n_k\in N$ are such that $N$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ that contains $n_1,\ldots,n_k$. This can then be potentially simplified.
So here you would get the presentation in $(1)$, which can then be simplified as given.

Thanks. So $G/N$ is genrated by $u=xN$ and $v=yN$, where $u^5=1$ and $v^2=1$?

@boaz : yes. ${}{}$
